# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 267911176 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 125MB until OOM

Tags: android, kotlin

i have this code to read data from xml file written in Kotlin

```
    val _is = resources.openRawResource(+R.xml.data)
    val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(_is))
    val data = StringBuffer()
    val line = reader.readLine()
    while (line != null) {
        data.append(line!! + "\n")
        //Log.d("aa",line.toString())
    }
    val resourceData = (data.toString())
```

the xml file data contains

```
<questions>

    <question>aaa</question>
    <question>bbb</question>
    <question>ccc</question>


</questions>
```

and i always get wrond data and also had this exception 
what is the problem ?

Comment: If your data is in XML, use an XML resource (`res/xml/`), and use `openXmlResource()` to open a parser on its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be reading the same line over and over again. Because the loop will never end, you will eventually run out of memory and crash the program.

```
val line = reader.readLine()     // 1
while (line != null) {           // 2
    data.append(line!! + "\n")   // 3
}
```

1 - Have the reader read the next line of data into `line`

2 - If line is not null, keep going

3 - Append the line to data. Go to step 2.

What you need to do at the end of the loop is to read the next line, so the while loop can evaluate it for null. You also need to make `line` a `var` so you can change it.

```
var line = reader.readLine()       // <-- Change val to var
while (line != null) {           
    data.append(line!! + "\n")   
    line = reader.readLine()       // <-- Add this
}
```

Comment: The exception is gone i tried to print the result at the end and i got this imgur.com/a/NTSmduf how can i get only the data i want ?